# I have a problem with nodejs(mongoose) pagination in my blog site

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pagination, router

```
app.get("/yazilim",async (req,res)=>{
    const {page=1,limit=10}=req.query
    const blogs = await Blog.find().limit(limit*1).skip((page-1)*limit)
    res.render("yazilim",{
        blogs
    })
})
```

When I go to page 2, express won't render the yazilim page (http://localhost:3000/yazilim/?page=2&limit=10). The pagination system is working correctly when I run in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the request URL is incorrect, can you try using it without the `/`?

```
http://localhost:3000/yazilim?page=2&limit=10
```

Comment: Oh yeah it was a simple mistake , thank you.